# Is there a way to know when a minority of the data is telling the truth?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, percentages

I am working with temperature data obtained from a network, and i need to identify when temperature sensings are legitimate(Haven't been modified by someone). To find this out, i must  compare new sensings with the ones the network has collected already.

The problem is: when more than fifty percent of the data i have is illegitimate, i.e cannot be trusted, is there a way to reliably tell when the minority of the data is telling the truth?

Comment: Have you tried applying [Benford's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law) to the data?

Comment: You would need some standard against which to compare the suspect data values, historical values (suspect values not typical of what has been seen before), theoretical values (unimaginably high, low, stable), and so on.